# how to convert plain php request to yii framework

Tags: php, yii, request

Previously there is php request like

```
$bidStart = isset($_REQUEST['sales_start']) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_REQUEST['sales_start'])) : date('Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday -6 weeks'));
```

now I write this in `yii framework` like this

```
$sales_start = Yii::app()->request->getParam('sales_start', '' );

$bidStart = isset($sales_start) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($sales_start)) : date('Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday -6 weeks')

);
```

but this is not working in browser gives error 
A script inn this movie causing adobe flash player to run slowly. if you continue to run this cause your computer unresponsive.

Comment: above code does not seem to cause error like that rather it has nothing to do with this. Are you sure nothing is running in your browser`s other tabs?

Comment: exactly what does this PHP (server-side) code have to do with Flash (client-side)?

Comment: actually sir i use fusion chart API and this request is call to this chart method. if i use only request means first one then its run fine.

Comment: but when i run with $sales_start = Yii::app()->request->getParam('sales_start', '' );

$bidStart = isset($sales_start) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($sales_start)) : date('Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday -6 weeks')

);

Comment: then i got that error

Answer (score 0):

```
$sales_start = Yii::app()->request->getParam('sales_start', '' );

$bidStart = isset($sales_start) ?
```

$sales_start will always be set, even it if it '' that still means it is set. Try
`$bidStart = !empty($sales_start) ?`